# Create a tar.gz for each folder in Gradle with Tar Task

Tags: gradle, groovy

I have a project that has a folder structure like this

```
blue/folder1
blue/folder2
red/folder3
red/folder4
```

and in Gradle I would like to tar up these folders individually so that the output looks like:

```
build/
  tar/
    blue/
      folder1.tar.gz
      folder2.tar.gz
    red/
      folder3.tar.gz
      folder4.tar.gz
```

Is that possible? How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
apply plugin: 'base'

['blue', 'red'].each { colour -> 
    file(colour).listFiles().each { File folder ->
        if (folder.directory) {
           Task tarTask = tasks.create(name: "tar${colour.capitalize()}${folder.capitalize()}", type: Tar) {
               from folder
               destinationDir = "${buildDir}/${colour}"
               archiveName = "${folder}.tar"
           }
           assemble.dependOn tarTask
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how I might access this task from 'maven-publish'? If I try the traditional MavenPublication with artifact 'tarTask' it says `Could not get unknown property 'tarTask' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.DefaultArtifactHandler.`

Comment: To get the .gz, don't you need to add `compression = Compression.GZIP` as one of the parameters for the tar task? Otherwise you're just making a tarball with a .gz extension.

Comment: @Fodder - no, it's supposed to figure out the format from the extension; you only need the "compression" setting if your format differs. See: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html